# jQuery: How to keep tooltip open on hover

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm working on a way to display a tooltip and keeping it open while the mouse hovers it.

It's relatively easy to do with css3, but my challenge is that 1) it should work in IE7 and 2) I only have jQuery version 1.3.2 avaliable.

So far I have this js:

```
$(function() {
     $('.circle').hover(function() {
         $(this).find('.tooltip').fadeIn(250);
     }, function() {
         $(this).find('.tooltip').fadeOut(250);
     });
});
```

and it's looking like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/w24Lxbg7/10/), but how can I keep the tooltips open so that the links inside them can be clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/w24Lxbg7/16/) seems to work. Cleaned up the css a bit and among other things removing `pointer-events: none;`